# Deleting roaming profile AppData folder in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have a machine, where different users can login with their credentials.

I have an application which gets installed on this machine. Different users login to this application using their individual credentials. As a result, under each users (UserName)\AppData\Roaming a new folder gets created by name DummyData.

When the admin uninstalls this application, I need to delete the DummyData folder created under different logins, if I use %APPDATA% I end up getting current logged in users' AppData folder. Is there a way, I can end up obtaining all the logged in users and if any DummyData folder created under AppData folder so that I can delete all of them.

thanks

Comment: Did you mean you want to delete a specfic folder named "DummyData" found into %APPDATA% ?

Comment: @Hackoo I have re-phrased the question, would that help?

Comment: @Hackoo DummyData folder is created in the %Appdata% folder of different users so I need to delete all of them.

Comment: Well, it is possible, but it is very complicated. But in the first place, why do you want to delete a folder from user profiles at uninstall? Typically when an application is being uninstalled it should not delete any files from the user profile(not to mention different user profiles). Couldn't it be an alternative to create this folder under Programdata? This way every user could access it. But if you still want to do it, you need to read the registry(HKEY_Users) to get every SID, then convert them to username.